# Can I conclude from here that $\ker T=\{0\}$ only?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ be the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $n$.

Let $T:P_n\to P_{n+1}$ be the map $T(p(x))=p'(x)-\int_{0}^{x}p(t)dt$, I need to find the dimension of kernel, we see that $\ker T=\{p(x):{d^2p(x)\over dx^2}=p(x)\}$

Can I conclude from here that $\ker T=\{0\}$ only?

Comment: Is $P_n$ the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ with degree at most $n$?

Comment: @DanielRust Yes That is.....

Comment: Hint: If the degree of $p$ is $k$, what is the degree of $p''$?

Comment: What about $p(x) = e^x$?

Comment: Sorry, I have believed that $p(x)$ was whatever function. It is not defined at the beguining xD. Oh I see that it is defined in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If $p''=p$ then, deriving $n$ more times, you get: $0=D_n p''=D_n p=n!a_n$, so $a_n=0$. Now deriving $n-1$ times, you can conclude that $a_{n-1}=0$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $p\in\ker T$ then $p'(x)=\int_0^xp(t)\:dt$. Suppose $p\neq 0$ has degree $0\leq k\leq n$. What do you know about the degree of $p'$ and the degree of $\int_0^xp(t)\:dt$?